# MySQL calculate punctuality from given late percentage

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL that returns each user_id and their attendance_percentage between given dates. It also gives the punctuality. This works well. However, to calculate the punctuality I am subtracting the late percentage from 100. For this to work a user needs to have attendance percentage greater than 0. Because if a user has 0% attendance then the punctuality becomes 100% because they don't have any late values at all (and this is incorrect)

Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this in the SQL?

In other words, Is there a way to say if (avg(late_value)*100) is greater than 0 then 100-(avg(late_value)*100?

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    AVG(value)*100 AS attendance_percentage, 
    100-(avg(late_value)*100) AS punctuality 
      FROM test t
WHERE t.session_date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-15'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: If any individual has 0% attendance then you have no data on which to measure their punctuality. It's unknown, so you shouldn't actually report it as a numerical value at all - 0% would be as invalid/incorrect as 100%.

Comment: Correct, so if punctuality is returned as 0 then I would like to not do the 100-(avg(late_value)*100) only if its greater than 0 then do 100-(avg(late_value)*100)

Comment: Have a look at mysql control https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    AVG(value)*100 AS attendance_percentage, 
    100-(avg(late_value)*100) AS punctuality, if (avg(late_value)*100)>0, 100-(avg(late_value)*100,0) 
      FROM test t
WHERE t.session_date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-15'
GROUP BY user_id
```

I can't test it out, but it looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql
this is not the best solution but it may work:

```
if (select value... >0)
{-- do whatever}
else{--do something different}
```